# Wrong variable is loaded with os.getenv(), not the variable in .env

Tags: python, environment-variables

**.env**

```
STAGING_BUCKET=our-staging-bucket
```

**common.py** (in same directory as .env)

```
import os
STAGING_BUCKET = os.getenv('STAGING_BUCKET')
print(STAGING_BUCKET)
```

When we run our airflow project locally, we receive a different value `diff-staging-bucket` for our STAGING_BUCKET variable. We recently changed this variable in our .env from `diff-staging-bucket` to `our-staging-bucket`. It seems like `os.getenv('STAGING_BUCKET')` is grabbing a globally saved `STAGING_BUCKET` variable, rather than the one in the .env file, as we can run this code locally in python from our home directory and the old `diff-staging-bucket` is still returned.

How can we straighten this out so that we receive the correct `.env` variable here

**EDIT** I ran `env` from the command line and yes there is a global STAGING_BUCKET variable that is `diff-staging-bucket`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.getenv` gets environment variables. Environment variables are usually set, in unix, by shell command such as `export` or `setenv` (depending on the shell). Those commands may be in shell init files, such as `.bashrc` or `.cshrc`

`.env` is not one of them. What you put in that file has no specific meaning. It is just a file. It has nothing to do with `os.getenv`.

I guess that confusion comes from the fact that in docker (but you never mentioned docker, neither in your question nor in any tags. I just surmise that previous experience with docker is the reason why you, wrongly, believe that `.env` contains environment variable), .env files are used to set the environment variable that are inserted in the generated docker images; so that inside those images, there are such `bashrc` files that contain those variables. But if you are not in an OS generated by a tool like docker-compose, from config files like `.env`, there is no reason to expect that `os.getenv` should know what is in a `.env` file.

Comment: yes we are running airflow in docker, that is correct

Answer (score 2):

`os.getenv` or `os.environ.get` both get environment variables which are usually set, in your kernel.

But if you're interested in reading environment variables from `.env` file you can use `python-dotenv` package; It reads What you put in that file as your config:

First, install it via *pip*:

```bash
pip install python-dotenv
```

and for example, you have *foo.py* you want to read *`.env`* variables in it and its directory structure is like below:

```
.
├── .env
└── foo.py
```

So your *`foo.py`* module should be like this:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()  # take environment variables from .env.

# Code of your application, which uses environment variables (e.g. from `os.environ` or
# `os.getenv`) as if they came from the actual environment.
```

Reference:

The above example was taken from [python-dotenv-docs](https://saurabh-kumar.com/python-dotenv/); you can find out more about other use cases of this package in its documentation.